# What does "== RESTART <path> ==" in the IDLE Shell mean?

Tags: python, python-idle

I have a simple script I wrote, and when trying to run it (F5) , I get this msg:

> ================== RESTART: C:\Users\***\Desktop\tst.py ==================

I restarted the shell, reopened the script, but still, the same msg appears.
I use python 3.5.1 and I tried to simplify the script as much as possible, but I still get this result. Now my script is only one line with a simple `print(1)` command and I still get this msg.

Was there something wrong with the shell installation?

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong?

Comment: because it never happened to me, and restart won't help

Comment: The message is simply telling you that your script has been restarted. That's what you told it to do, right?

Comment: IDLE restarts to clear the variables and reloads your file... I think that's what you are seeing

Comment: OK, how do I stop that? and why it even tries to do that? never saw that before... and no, I didn't tell it to restart, I just had a print function

Comment: For advanced python programming, try using a proper IDE like PyCharm, Eclipse, or Spyder, etc

Comment: @cricket_007 this is hardly advanced IMO

Comment: Sure. I'm just stating that IDLE isn't really useful outside simple scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a simple script I wrote, and when trying to run it (F5)

That's the hotkey for IDLE to run a file. It is not ordering to do anything. It's a log statement to explicitly declare that your namespace is being cleared and the file is going to be ran fresh again.

> no, I didn't tell it to restart

But you did... You pressed F5

Comment: but why is it there? I almost positively sure I never saw it before

Comment: IDLE 3 may have different behavior than IDLE 2. I know I have seen it before

Comment: IDLE is written in Python. Have a look at the source code if you really want to find out under what circumstances it prints that message.

Comment: One can restart IDLE's shell either with Shell => Restart Shell Cntl-F6 or Run => Run Module F5.  Two years ago I added the path for the second case so there would be a record that the workspace was initialized, and how.  This can be especially helpful edit and run multiple files.

Comment: I'm wondering why no one told him how to do what he's actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing is happening with my shell. In the older versions, this does not happen. I've also noticed that when I press Python 3.5.2 Module Docs, I have my Internet browser open up and I see my directory being displayed onscreen. It looks like:

C:\Users\mycomputername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DLLs.

Is that suppose to happen? Is that secured? I don't know.

I've also found that this prints out whenever I "imported" something. So if I use an import command, and put it right before the line of my random name, it will print out that "RESTART" thing. It's always at the beginning. Or what it reads as the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

CIsForCookies, my guess is that you don't actually have a complete script; maybe you have just a function definition and you haven't included a line to run that function. (I had this problem and then remembered to call the function I defined; the problem went away.)

Answer (score 0):

You may have made the same mistake as me and ran a program and then you wonder why RESTART  is all that shows up.  My program was working perfectly I just did not print anything or ask for any input so it ran and was done with the program and nothing showed up.